# show answer when timer is stopped

Tags: javascript, php

I have created a quiz system where I tried to create a condition which is just simple one if time is up then correct answer will be shown up and the button would be disabled but I am confused and unable to make some logic about I need you guys help I hope you will help me out

Thank You

```
<?php 
function answer() {
    $answer = $_POST["ans"];
    if($answer == 'b') {
        echo "Correct answer!";
    } else {
        echo "Wrong answer!";
    }
}
$correct = 'b';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Quiz Sample</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function countdown(secs, elem, correct) {
    var answer  = correct;
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+secs+" Seconds"; 
    if(secs < 1) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        element.innerHTML = "Timer completed Correct answer is"+answer+" !";                
    }
    secs--;
    var timer = setTimeout('countdown('+secs+', "'+elem+'")', 1000);
  }
  </script>
  </head>
<body>
    <?php    
        if(isset($_POST["sub"])) {
            echo answer();
        }
    ?>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <form method="POST" action="quiz_test.php">
    <p>The question followed is below:</p>
        <input type="radio" value="a" name="ans" /> A
        <input type="radio" value="b" name="ans" /> B
        <input type="radio" value="c" name="ans" /> C
        <input type="radio" value="d" name="ans" /> D
    <input type="submit" name="sub" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">countdown(3, 'status', '<?php echo $correct; ?>');</script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed one parameter which is the variable `correct`

you also don't need to put an extra quote on your `elem` variable since it's already a string..

```
setTimeout('countdown('+secs+', '+elem+', '+correct +')', 1000);
```

also add a code to disable your submit button

Answer (score 1):

can do like that ... check it out ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Quiz Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <form method="POST" action="quiz_test.php">
    <p>The question followed is below:</p>
        <input type="radio" value="a" name="ans" class="a" /> A
        <input type="radio" value="b" name="ans" class="b" /> B
        <input type="radio" value="c" name="ans" class="c" /> C
        <input type="radio" value="d" name="ans" class="d" /> D
    <input type="submit" name="sub" />
    </form>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      var correctAns = "a";
      setTimeout(showUpCorrectAns, 1000, correctAns);
     });

     function showUpCorrectAns(correctAns){
      $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true);
      $('input.'+correctAns).attr('checked','checked');
     }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you why the condition fails is that although you are calling the function "countdown()" recursively, you were not passing the correct answer i.e. "var answer".

The corrected code is:

```
<?php 
function answer() {
    $answer = $_POST["ans"];
    if($answer == 'b') {
        echo "Correct answer!";
    } else {
        echo "Wrong answer!";
    }
}
$correct = 'b';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Quiz Sample</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function countdown(secs, elem, correct) {
    if (secs >= 0){
    console.log(correct);
    var answer  = correct;
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+secs+" Seconds"; 
    if(secs < 1) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        element.innerHTML = "Timer completed. Correct answer is "+ answer +" !";                
    }
    secs--;
    var timer = setTimeout('countdown('+secs+', "'+elem+'","'+ answer +'")', 1000);
  }
}
  </script>
  </head>
<body>
    <?php    
        if(isset($_POST["sub"])) {
            echo answer();
        }
    ?>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <form method="POST" action="quiz_test.php">
    <p>The question followed is below:</p>
        <input type="radio" value="a" name="ans" /> A
        <input type="radio" value="b" name="ans" /> B
        <input type="radio" value="c" name="ans" /> C
        <input type="radio" value="d" name="ans" /> D
    <input type="submit" name="sub" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">countdown(10, 'status', '<?php echo $correct; ?>');</script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

a. You haven't passed the third parameter for countdown()
b. You missed `document.getElementById('sub').disabled=true;`
c. Timer not stopped correcty

```html
<?php 
function answer() {
    $answer = $_POST["ans"];
    if($answer == 'b') {
        echo "Correct answer!";
    } else {
        echo "Wrong answer!";
    }
}
$correct = 'b';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Quiz Sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var timer;

        function countdown(secs, elem, correct) {
            var answer = correct;
            var element = document.getElementById(elem);
            element.innerHTML = "Please wait for " + --secs + " Seconds";
            timer = setTimeout('countdown(' + secs + ', "' + elem + '", "' + answer + '")', 1000);
            if (secs < 1) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                element.innerHTML = "Timer completed Correct answer is " + answer + " !";
                document.getElementById('sub').disabled = true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php if(isset($_POST[ "sub"])) { echo answer(); } ?>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <form method="POST" action="quiz_test.php">
        <p>The question followed is below:</p>
        <input type="radio" value="a" name="ans" />A
        <input type="radio" value="b" name="ans" />B
        <input type="radio" value="c" name="ans" />C
        <input type="radio" value="d" name="ans" />D
        <input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        countdown(3, 'status', '<?php echo $correct; ?>');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Remember in the code snippet here, PHP won't be executed, but the right answer will be printed when you run appropriately.

Comment: Really much appreciated thank you very much it was my silly mistake :)

Comment: Glad that I helped you, make sure to accept to close this question